# Realize Countdown using PHP and JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to write a countdown, which get the time from a server (php) and then counts down on the client side (JavaScript). Unfortunately I have only a few experience with JavaScript or JQuery. At this time the script looks like this:

```
<?php 
    $endTime = mktime(00, 00, 00, 01, 01, 2012); 
    $actTime = time(); 
    $difTime = $endTime - $actTime;
    $seconds = $difTime;
?>

<script  type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.setInterval(function() {
        var seconds = $('div#timer').html();                    
        var updateTime = eval(seconds)- eval(1);                    
        $('div#timer').html(updateTime);
    }, 1000);
});
</script>

<div id="timer"><?php echo $seconds ?></div>
```

Now I want to convert the remaining seconds into days, months, minutes and seconds. However, I do not really know how I should realize that with the function
setInterval. Can anyone help me? Maybe there are better ways as working with the UNIX-Timestamp?

Thank you in advance!

Martin

Comment: Note that `setInterval()` (and `setTimeout()`) don't guarantee that the callback will be executed exactly at the interval you specified, so it's generally a good idea to get the current time on each iteration (and calculate the offset from the original server-specified time as appropriate). For the same reason you generally get a smoother looking clock if you set the interval to something significantly smaller than 1 second: say 50-100ms - that way if the interval gets a little delayed it doesn't feel like the counter jumped as much.

Answer (score 0):

To use seconds is quiet the best way. And only to count down the seconds and calculate the rest from them.
You just need to extend the function defined to execute every 1 second. Use mod and div with math.floor to calculate the days and hours from the seconds, build new string with it and put it into the div.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this script for countdown this is a best script for countdown.
http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html